# getting error while pushing folder from local to git using git command

Tags: github, gitlab, push

```
          error: src refspec git@gitlab.com does not match any.
          error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'
```

i'm trying to push my project to gitlab but im getting again and again the same error i have tried n number of times and i have seen many answer but none worked me please can any one help me in getting out of this ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the names of the inputs instead of the column names from your database.

```
$fname = $row['fname'];
$lname = $row['lname'];
$email = $row['email'];
$contactnumber = $row['number'];
$age = $row['age'];
```

should be:

```
$fname = $row['FirstName'];
$lname = $row['LastName'];
$email = $row['Email'];
$contactnumber = $row['Contactnumber'];
$age = $row['Age'];
```

You also shouldn't use PHP opening shortcodes

```
<?= $fname ?>
```

should be:

```
<?php echo $fname ?>
```