# unable to push file from local folder to gitlab

Tags: gitlab, push

i'm trying to push folders from my local htdocs to gitlab but im getting again and again the same error. i have tried all the solution but im not getting any solution for this please can any one help me in this. thanks in advance

```
     error: src refspec git@gitlab.com does not match any.
    error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'
```

Comment: What command are you running that generates this output?

Comment: please provide the following info: `git remove -v` and `git status`

Comment: Is is in php? As in https://stackoverflow.com/q/54491879/6309?